cloud-init to automatically select smallest disk to install onto
I'm trying to automate Ubuntu Dekstop installations onto different laptops.
I have this working just perfect with an autoinstall.yaml file, and it does setup the system with an encrypted disk.
The problem I now face are that some laptops are configured with 2 SSD disks. Unfortunately cloud-init do the installatio onto the bigger disk and I need that reserved for data.
Is there a way to have cloud-init always select the smallest disk? Or in worse case, perhaps ask the user to select the disk to install onto?
I use the storage module like this for doing the disk setup:
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      sizing-policy: all
      password: '?????'

